Firebase Storage Bucket Domain Shows " firebasestorage.app " Instead of " appspot.com "
I’m currently working on a Firebase project where I’m trying to configure Firebase Storage. I’m using the Spark Plan (free tier), and I noticed two issues:
1.The storageBucket in my Firebase config shows:
storageBucket: "chattr-s1.firebasestorage.app" 
Instead of the usual appspot.com domain format.
2.I can’t access Storage in the Firebase Console.
It prompts me to "Upgrade the project billing plan," even though:
I am on the Spark Plan (free tier).
I haven’t uploaded any files or used Storage yet.
My Questions:
1.Why does the storageBucket show firebasestorage.app instead of appspot.com?
2.Why can’t I access Firebase Storage in my project even though I’m on the Spark Plan and have not exceeded any usage limits?
3.Is this a configuration issue or an expected change in Firebase storage URLs?
4.Is there a specific step I need to take to enable Firebase Storage?
What I Tried:
1.I checked the Firebase Console under the Storage section, but it still shows the message:  "To use Storage, upgrade your project's billing plan."
2.I verified that I am on the Spark Plan (free tier) under Billing & Usage.

I attempted to set up Firebase Storage in my project code with the following configuration:

However, the domain for storageBucket still shows firebasestorage.app instead of appspot.com.
I tried searching for Firebase Storage usage limits under the Spark Plan to ensure I hadn’t exceeded any limits, but I have not used Storage at all.

What I Expected:

I expected to access Firebase Storage under the Spark Plan since it includes 5GB of free storage.
I expected the storageBucket domain to default to appspot.com (e.g., chattr-s1.appspot.com) like it does in standard Firebase projects.


There were changes to the product that you need to be aware of. Neither of your expectations are valid now.
Firebase Storage is no longer available on the free tier.  You must upgrade to use it.  See the documentation:

Important: The following changes to pricing plan requirements are
happening for Cloud Storage for Firebase. Learn more in the FAQs.

Starting October 30, 2024, your Firebase project must be on the pay-as-you-go Blaze pricing plan to provision a new Cloud Storage for
Firebase default bucket. The bucket can optionally use the "Always
Free" tier for Google Cloud Storage.

Starting October 1, 2025, your Firebase project must be on the pay-as-you-go Blaze pricing plan to maintain access to your default
bucket and all other Cloud Storage resources. Any *.appspot.com
default bucket will maintain its current no-cost level of usage even
on the Blaze pricing plan.



See also:

Firebase cloud storage ( for projects)

The name of the buckets have changed.  This is also covered in the documentation:

Note: Starting October 30, 2024, all new default Cloud Storage buckets have the name format PROJECT_ID.firebasestorage.app. Any default buckets created before that date have the name format PROJECT_ID.appspot.com. Learn more in the FAQs.

If you click through to the FAQs, you will read:

Important: Here are the summarized key points of the FAQs in this
section (but make sure to review each FAQ below for details):

Starting October 30, 2024, all newly provisioned default Cloud Storage buckets will have the name format of PROJECT_ID.firebasestorage.app.
These buckets will follow Google Cloud Storage pricing and usage, which provides an "Always Free" tier for buckets in US-CENTRAL1, US-EAST1, and US-WEST1.
There are no changes to any existing PROJECT_ID.appspot.com default buckets (as long as you upgrade your project to the pay-as-you-go Blaze pricing plan by October 1, 2025).


You can still use the product for free up to the documented limits, but your project must be on a payment plan so that it can be billed for any overages.
